# How to Copy azure devops build to local machine

Tags: build, azure-devops

I have created  a build definition using Azure devops online, as i know the build is getting created in azure VMs. How can i copy/share the build to a shared location in my local machine

Answer (score 1):

Publish your build outputs as artifacts, then you can either use a release definition to deploy the build outputs, or manually download them to your machine.

Answer (score 1):

If you have public shared location with public IP then you can directly archive the artifacts to that location.

If not, you need to install a VSTS Build agent in your network, then you can archive the artifacts to local shared location.